# Сменил сервер с windows на *nix. Появилось куча папок. Что с ними делать?

Tags: apache, сервер, linux

Папки:

> `.awstats
> .cpan
> .fast
> .fast-php
> .php
> .ssh
> http
> logs`

и файлы:

> `.bash_logout
> .bash_profile
> .bashrs
> .mounted`

Если кто знает ресурс по работе сервера **`Apache 2.* [l19, Linux], aux1 / fcgi`**,
напишите. Если не знаете - буду сам искать. Когда работал по виндой, там только одна папка была http. Теперь такое добро высыпало, что я не знаю, как им воспользоваться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да ничего не делать. На каталоги, чье имя начинается с точки, не обращайте пока внимания. Это аналог «скрытых» каталогов в Windows, обычно там программы хранят свои настройки.

Например,
.awstats — это файлы анализатора логов AWStats
.cpan — это файлы установщика перловых модулей
и так далее.

Так что на самом деле у вас «своих» папок только две: http и logs.

Ну а

> ресурс по работе сервера Apache 2.* [l19, Linux], aux1 / fcgi

известно, какой — [httpd.apache.org](http://httpd.apache.org/).

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Хоть стало понятно что к чему. Буду изучать.

Comment: Ну и как в windows, вы можете настроить, хотите вы видеть dot-файлы или нет (в менеджере ftp или что там у вас). Например, обычный ls их не показывает без ключика -a.

Хотя, конечно, лучше их видеть и потихоньку изучить, зачем нужны .bash_profile и .ssh хотя бы.

Comment: И это… спасибо за «спасибо», но если вас ответ устроил, то не забудьте его принять, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Что делать, что делать. Стандартный сервер получился. Теперь просто с ним работать и все. А то привыкаете, что был апач и доступ только по хттп.